# Need help transferring the contents of a 1D array to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I parsed through a csv file which is made up of specific columns and rows and put that information into a `String[] array1D`. If I print, for example, `array1D[0]` (on the file column at index 0 is the column that has the number for each row) it prints out all the row numbers. For the rest of the columns its the same deal. How can I transfer the contents of this 1d array into a multi-dimensional array? Ive tried messing around with nested for loops but my implementation is flawed or its something that just cant be done with a for loops.

EDIT:
For my csv file in question column at index 0 is a column that numbers each row. If I print out `String[0] array1D`it will print

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

EDIT 2: Actually I found a workaround for my problem. I needed to put my array into a 2d array so I could do certain functions like averaging all the numbers in a certain column. However I could use a if statement and put the column that I want to do any function on into a new arraylist. I could then apply the function to that arraylist.

Comment: Can you post an example output and what it should be

Answer (score 0):

I will explain you the concept. Given that i don't have exact information i wouldn't be able to give you exact formula for that.

First of all, you have to make sure that the column `# of rows` of each column is same throughout the columns. For the sake of this discussion lets say you have `10` rows and `4 columns`. In total, you have `40` items in single array.

Now here is the tricky part. For every index which is `index%columnCount == 0` is your new row in 2D array. so in this case e.g. `0/10 == 0` is array at index `0`. `10%10 == 0` will be your new row at index 1 and finally `30%10 == 0` will be your `3` row in your 2D array.

I hope you have got the idea. Let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: This may need more explaining but to me this sounds like a situation where every element from the csv file has its own index in the 1d array. For me at column index 0, every element stored at (row x, column 0) is stored at index 0 on my 1d array.

Comment: could you please add a sample in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items are to be in one row then you can break the 1d array into the 2D array. Once there is an identifier you can break the array into seperate rows from there